# Regex: Check that the string has 40 digits and that it contains no more than two letters

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to find a regex expression that checks if a string has 40 digits and if there are max. 2 letters in it.

For example:
This string should not be valid, because there are three letters in it
"0000001300708030000009202303010437**S**001**CX**".

This strings should be valid, because there are only two letters in it "00000013007080300000092023030104370001**CX**" and "00000013007080300000092023030104370**S**010**X**".

This strings should be valid, because there are one or no letters in it
"0000001300708030000009202303010437000177" and "000000130070803000000920230301043700010**X**".

My approach is to divide the different possibilities as group and than limit them to 40 characters, but it does not work. My groups are a variation of no letters, one letter or two letters in different positions in the expiration.

Number/s = A
One letter = B

`A or AB or ABB or ABAB or ABBA or BBAA ...` and so on

But maybe there is a better approach?

I am grateful for solutions.

Comment: Where is regex being used? Engine will determine available solutions. Have you tried any regexs yet? `(?=^.{40}$)` would be 40 character string.

Comment: Your sample strings are all 38 characters, aren't they. Please improve your question and include your pattern (how far you got). You want to match 40 alphanumeric characters with max two letters?

Comment: *"checks if a string has 40 digits"*: a string with 38 characters can never have 40 digits... Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I've updated the strings to 40 digits. I'm also just looking for a solution in RegEx pattern form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion so that when there are three occurrences of a letter, the string is rejected:

```
^(?!(?:\d*[A-Za-z]){3})[A-Za-z\d]{40}$
```

Break-down:

- `[A-Za-z\d]{40}`: exactly 40 characters that are English letters or digits
- `^    $`: match the whole input (so the whole input must be exactly 40 characters)
- `(?!    )`: negative look ahead assertion: what is specified here should *not* match:
- `\d*[A-Za-z]`: zero or more digits followed by one English letter
- `(?:    ){3}`: repeat three times

So the negative assertion is:

- `(?!(?:\d*[A-Za-z]){3})`: it should not be possible to match three times the sequence of some digits followed by an English letter, as that would mean there are three letters in the string.

Note that your examples have only **38** characters, so none of them would match. If you wanted it to work with 38, then replace that 40 with 38 in the regex.

Comment: That's working thanks a lot! Also got a bit better understanding for look aheads. Awesome answer.